# Bloomberg API - Session not starting

Tags: blpapi

First off all do I need to have a bloomberg account to experiment with the API. I am running Win 8 64 bit. I ran the C++ version (no .Net). I ran the first sample to test it.

If I do need  to have a Bloomberg account, is there any other  free way to pull market data. I know Yahoo and Google do it. But google closed their support, and have no experience on Yahoo.

Comment: Does bloomberg redirect their support calls to SO?

Answer (score 0):

Only if You want to experiment with the data. It's very business centric. If You want reliable up-to-date market data, than You need a reliable source. Bloomberg is so expensive, because even banks rely on it.

Whenever two traders (not from same bank) want to deal, they accept that the exchange rate is coming from Bloomberg for example. Without that they are not on the same page. Other big one is Reuters.

Basically You can have other means to gather market data, just the usefulness of the data will be "only for garage project". No one will deal with You without stating Your market data source.